# get certain years out of other sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

At work we have a worksheet with serveral (40-50) worksheets. Each worksheets represent a certain study. Several people are on each sheet with a name, surname, start of study (date), birthday, etc. And we have one worksheet with an overview. (worksheet study 1, worksheet study 2, worksheet study 3).

Is there any way, that I can place a column on overview, and filter on the people that have joined a study. (so all people that joined a study in year 2016, but not those that did not.) I have a column with the start date of a study, but people can join a study after a study has started.

I've already tried to use a filter, and tried some stuff with data validation, but Im nowhere close to a a solution. Is there anyone who can put me on the right track?

Comment: I'm not an Excel guru, but 50 worksheets sounds like being on the verge of not maintainable, and error prone.  If I were you, I'd bring that data into a database, where it would likely be easy to answer your question.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I always recommend DB's for this (either be it sql, access or filemaker) but this is an excel made by someone in the "early days" :D . Seems, I will have to introduce them to one of these solutions.

Thank you anyway for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here:

- I'm assuming that each worksheet for a study is in the same format
- The people in a study (the data you want) is in a standardised location on each sheet

One solution would be to do some code in VBA. You could iterate through each sheet (that is not called 'Overview', obviously) and assign to a variable the range where the details you want to check are stored, then iterate through each cell in that range, and record in an array the names of anyone who matches the criteria.

For example, if each of your Study sheets has a list of participants like this:
[Participant List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwE1w.jpg)

You would define the range variable as [Worksheet].Range("A5:A12"), and say:

```
For Each <cell> in <range>.Cells
If Year(<Worksheet>.Cells(<cell>.Row, <cell>.column + 1).Value) = 2017 Then
<assign the contents of <cell> to an Array>
Next <cell>
```

Once you'd gone through each worksheet, the contents of the array could be output to any desired location, either on the Overview sheet or elsewhere.
This would be a basic idea of one way to do it. I would stress though that your data sounds like exactly the kind of thing that an MS Access Database would be ideal for (I know from personal experience however that some companies/departments are afraid of anything that isn't Excel, so I feel your pain!)